# Notepad++ function list for all open documents?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to listen all functions for all currently opened documents with the built in function list feature?

Currently it only lists functions on the given page I am editing, which is kind of annoying! I would like to see all of them some how so i can switch between documents quicker.

Comment: You mean like a "go to Definition" kind of feature, something that an IDE offers?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this Dave? I've just started using function list, and immediately wondered why this feature wasn't available to activate, as it's so clearly useful (especially given that the file has a [-] next to it, indicating you might want to collapse the file's list due to lack of space for other files...)

Comment: Nope I didn't find a way.

Comment: any update here? this is clearly a must have for notepad++ !